# div to 0 handling excel

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula, excel-tables, vba

So I have this issue, I have two tables one is employees, and another one is the projects.

Employees Table:

```
Year Name Type Jan Feb    
2018 Kevin Salary 5000 2000    
2018 Kevin Insurance 200 400    
2018 Alex Salary 3000 4000    
2018 Alex Insurance 300 400
```

Projects Table

```
Year Project_Name Employee_Name Jan_Hours_Worked Feb_Hours_Worked    
2018 Apple Alex 7 5    
2018 Apple Kevin 5 0    
2018 LG Kevin 0 3
```

Now I am creating a result list of all the projects and costs recurred for them in each month, what I need is for each project in Table 2 to find which employees are involved and then use that info to find costs from the Table 1 and calculate the hourly rate to charge for the projects in each month.

(e.g for project LG, I have Kevin working on that in Feb,for him company paid 2400(salary+insurance) and the hourly rate to charge in Feb then will be 2400 divided by total hours he spends on the project which is 3 hours.

For the project Apple in Feb, it would be Alex's: 4400/5, since Kevin didn't work any hours in Feb in this project. And when both of them works  for example as in Jan for the apple project then it should be Kevin's costs/hours he worked + Alex's costs/hours he worked in that month for that project.

Now I have the formula to calculate this which works fine unless I have the 0 value in the table.

> When it comes to the 0 it gives me division to zero error

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Employees[Feb], Employees[Name],Project[Employee_Name], Employees[Year], 2018 )/Project[Feb_Hours_Worked],--(Project[Project_Name]=K14))
```

How can I alter this formula to make that work for the above scenario without getting error and finding correct result for each month.

Comment: Wrap it in `IfError(... , result you want instead of error)`

Comment: Thanks but can you be more specific? because with if error, i will always stop runing the function if there is any division to zero, but that is not where I want to stop I want to be able to then move to the next item in the list and run the function for the entire table column and get the sumproduct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making this easy but I think I found something suitable :

[image]

Edit:

For DIV 0 Error, using the same set up as above in M9 cell :

`{=SUMPRODUCT(($J$2:$J$4=$K10)*(M$2:M$4*(IFERROR(SUMIF($B$2:$B$5,$K$2:$K$4,E$2:E$5)/SUMIF($K$2:$K$4,$K$2:$K$4,M$2:M$4),0))))}`

Validation with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

---

Edit 2 :

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT(M$2:M$9,(IFERROR(SUMIFS(E$2:E$17,$A$2:$A$17,$P5,$B$2:$B$17,$K$2:$K$9)/SUMIFS(M$2:M$9,$I$2:$I$9,$P5,$K$2:$K$9,$K$2:$K$9),0))*($I$2:$I$9=$P5)*($J$2:$J$9=$Q5))`

Validation with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Hi thank you very much, this seems to work with my initial test, only one thing how can I also include the year criteria to the above code to make sure it also takes info from the correct year?